# Using tables for fun and rep!

Tags: discussion

Now that we've got tables, I think we can start getting some more side-by-side Latin/Greek/English/Tagalog/Klingon textual comparisons going here.

I'd love to see something like what NewAdvent does with their Bible https://www.newadvent.org/bible/gen001.htm  It's pretty simple.  If you haven't checked out the lined page it's here [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support?cb=1)  the markdown explanation is also in the wysiwig editor.

The only real problem I see is a lack of intentional line breaks.  But maybe we could come up with a convention (or make sure we put verse numbers between stanzas?)

Anyway, it's a fun feature I hope you all try out (when appropriate), I'm sure I requested this on uservoice back in 2008 (at least I was thinking it), FWIW. So you can all thank me.  I'm also responsible for Star Wars Legos, as I wrote a letter to Lego in 1994 requesting it, in case you wanted to thank me again.

| Things I'd Always Wanted | Year Requested | Year Implemented |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Star Wars Legos | 1994 | 1999 |
| Tables in Markdown | 2008 | 2020 |
| Chinese Democracy | 1995 | 2008 |
| Peace on Earth | 1984 | 2021 |

Answer (score 4):

## Single column (for single language passage)

#### Example

| Gen. 18:22-25 |
| --- |
| <sup>22</sup>Then the men turned away from there and went toward Sodom, but Abraham still stood before the LORD. <sup>23</sup>And Abraham came near and said, "Would You also destroy the righteous with the wicked? <sup>24</sup>**Suppose there were fifty righteous within the city; would You also destroy the place and not spare it for the fifty righteous that were in it?** <sup>25</sup>Far be it from You to do such a thing as this, to slay the righteous with the wicked, so that the righteous should be as the wicked; far be it from You! Shall not the Judge of all the earth do right?" <sub>(*Holy Bible: New King James Version.* Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

#### Steps

1. Use the following template for the Markdown code:

   ```
   |Gen. 18:22-25|
   |:-------|
   |<sup>22</sup>Then the ... before the LORD. <sup>23</sup>And ... |
   ```
2. To add the source reference, append the following in the 3rd markdown line (without line break) before the final pipe ('|') character.  It **has to** be in the same line, otherwise it breaks into another table row.

   ```
   <br><sub>(*Holy Bible: New King James Version.* Nashville ... 1982)</sub>
   ```

## Multi column (for side by side translation)

#### Tips

- For intentional line breaks I use `<br>`
- For the indent I use the [U+00A0 character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) entered in Windows PC using keyboard shortcut Alt-0160
- For the verse number superscript I use `<sup>` `</sup>` followed by one U+00A0 character so automatic line break doesn't separate the verse number from the first word
- Another way to enter superscript is to use Unicode, but the vertical shift may not be as pronounced.  See the table below:

  | Digit | Unicode | PC Keyboard input method | Result (for copy+paste) |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 0 | U+2070 | Alt-08304 | ⁰ |
  | 1 | U+00B9 | Alt-0185 | ¹ |
  | 2 | U+00B2 | Alt-0178 | ² |
  | 3 | U+00B3 | Alt-0179 | ³ |
  | 4 | U+2074 | Alt-08308 | ⁴ |
  | 5 | U+2075 | Alt-08309 | ⁵ |
  | 6 | U+2076 | Alt-08310 | ⁶ |
  | 7 | U+2077 | Alt-08311 | ⁷ |
  | 8 | U+2078 | Alt-08312 | ⁸ |
  | 9 | U+2079 | Alt-08313 | ⁹ |
- For Hebrew, I use the right-left using right alignment column which renders the right to left flow nicely.  However the superscripts don't mix well with the Hebrew's right to left text flow; they cannot appear next to the first hebrew letter, but falls on the end of the first line (thus in the middle of the text).  I tried both the HTML method and the Unicode method, but didn't work.

#### Example: Psalm 1:1-2

**English + Hebrew example** (line breaks + indentation)

| ESV | Hebrew |
| --- | --- |
| <sup>1</sup> Blessed is the man who walks not in the counsel of the wicked nor stands in the way of sinners, nor sits in the seat of scoffers; <sup>2</sup> but his delight is in the law of the Lord, and on his law he meditates day and night. | אַ֥שְֽׁרֵי־הָאִ֗ישׁ אֲשֶׁ֤ר׀ לֹ֥א הָלַךְ֮ בַּעֲצַ֪ת רְשָׁ֫עִ֥ים וּבְדֶ֣רֶךְ חַ֭טָּאִים לֹ֥א עָמָ֑ד וּבְמוֹשַׁ֥ב לֵ֝צִ֗ים לֹ֣א יָשָֽׁב׃ כִּ֤י אִ֥ם בְּתוֹרַ֥ת יְהוָ֗ה חֶ֫פְצ֥וֹ וּֽבְתוֹרָת֥וֹ יֶהְגֶּ֗ה יוֹמָ֥ם וָלָֽיְלָה׃ |

**Greek + Latin example** (line breaks + indentation):

| Septuagint | Vulgate |
| --- | --- |
| <sup>1</sup> ΜΑΚΑΡΙΟΣ ἀνὴρ ὃς οὐκ ἐπορεύθη ἐν βουλῇ ἀσεβῶν καὶ ἐν ὁδῷ ἁμαρτωλῶν οὐκ ἔστη, καὶ ἐπὶ καθέδραν λοιμῶν οὐκ ἐκάθισεν· <sup>2</sup> ἀλλʼ ἢ ἐν τῷ νόμῳ Κυρίου τὸ θέλημα αὐτοῦ, καὶ ἐν τῷ νόμῳ αὐτοῦ μελετήσει ἡμέρας καὶ νυκτός. | <sup>1</sup> Beatus vir qui non abiit in consilio impiorum, et in via peccatorum non stetit, et in cathedra pestilentiae non sedit; <sup>2</sup> sed in lege Domini voluntas ejus, et in lege ejus meditabitur die ac nocte. |

**English + Hebrew + Greek + Latin** (one line break per verse, no indent):

| ESV | Hebrew | Septuagint | Vulgate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <sup>1</sup> Blessed is the man who walks not in the counsel of the wicked nor stands in the way of sinners, nor sits in the seat of scoffers; <sup>2</sup> but his delight is in the law of the Lord, and on his law he meditates day and night. | <sup>1</sup> אַ֥שְֽׁרֵי־הָאִ֗ישׁ אֲשֶׁ֤ר׀ לֹ֥א הָלַךְ֮ בַּעֲצַ֪ת רְשָׁ֫עִ֥ים וּבְדֶ֣רֶךְ חַ֭טָּאִים לֹ֥א עָמָ֑ד וּבְמוֹשַׁ֥ב לֵ֝צִ֗ים לֹ֣א יָשָֽׁב׃ <sup>2</sup> כִּ֤י אִ֥ם בְּתוֹרַ֥ת יְהוָ֗ה חֶ֫פְצ֥וֹ וּֽבְתוֹרָת֥וֹ יֶהְגֶּ֗ה יוֹמָ֥ם וָלָֽיְלָה׃ | <sup>1</sup> ΜΑΚΑΡΙΟΣ ἀνὴρ ὃς οὐκ ἐπορεύθη ἐν βουλῇ ἀσεβῶν, καὶ ἐν ὁδῷ ἁμαρτωλῶν οὐκ ἔστη, καὶ ἐπὶ καθέδραν λοιμῶν οὐκ ἐκάθισεν· <sup>2</sup> ἀλλʼ ἢ ἐν τῷ νόμῳ Κυρίου τὸ θέλημα αὐτοῦ, καὶ ἐν τῷ νόμῳ αὐτοῦ μελετήσει ἡμέρας καὶ νυκτός. | <sup>1</sup> Beatus vir qui non abiit in consilio impiorum, et in via peccatorum non stetit, et in cathedra pestilentiæ non sedit; <sup>2</sup> sed in lege Domini voluntas ejus, et in lege ejus meditabitur die ac nocte. |

**English + Hebrew + Greek + Latin** (no line breaks similar to [newadvent.org](https://www.newadvent.org/bible/psa001.htm), using Unicode superscripts):

| ESV | Hebrew | Septuagint | Vulgate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ¹ Blessed is the man who walks not in the counsel of the wicked nor stands in the way of sinners, nor sits in the seat of scoffers; ² but his delight is in the law of the Lord, and on his law he meditates day and night. | ¹ אַ֥שְֽׁרֵי־הָאִ֗ישׁ אֲשֶׁ֤ר׀ לֹ֥א הָלַךְ֮ בַּעֲצַ֪ת רְשָׁ֫עִ֥ים וּבְדֶ֣רֶךְ חַ֭טָּאִים לֹ֥א עָמָ֑ד וּבְמוֹשַׁ֥ב לֵ֝צִ֗ים לֹ֣א יָשָֽׁב׃ ² כִּ֤י אִ֥ם בְּתוֹרַ֥ת יְהוָ֗ה חֶ֫פְצ֥וֹ וּֽבְתוֹרָת֥וֹ יֶהְגֶּ֗ה יוֹמָ֥ם וָלָֽיְלָה׃ | ¹ ΜΑΚΑΡΙΟΣ ἀνὴρ ὃς οὐκ ἐπορεύθη ἐν βουλῇ ἀσεβῶν, καὶ ἐν ὁδῷ ἁμαρτωλῶν οὐκ ἔστη, καὶ ἐπὶ καθέδραν λοιμῶν οὐκ ἐκάθισεν· ² ἀλλʼ ἢ ἐν τῷ νόμῳ Κυρίου τὸ θέλημα αὐτοῦ, καὶ ἐν τῷ νόμῳ αὐτοῦ μελετήσει ἡμέρας καὶ νυκτός. | ¹ Beatus vir qui non abiit in consilio impiorum, et in via peccatorum non stetit, et in cathedra pestilentiæ non sedit; ² sed in lege Domini voluntas ejus, et in lege ejus meditabitur die ac nocte. |

Credits:

- Hebrew: [Lexham Hebrew-English Interlinear Bible](https://www.logos.com/product/2056/lexham-hebrew-english-interlinear-bible)
- Septuagint: [Lexham Greek-English Interlinear Septuagint: H.B. Swete Edition](https://www.logos.com/product/27440/lexham-greek-english-interlinear-septuagint-hb-swete-edition)

Comment: Ohh, that is really good looking - now all we need is a WYSIWIG editor!

Comment: If it's important that verses are kept together horizontally (which it may not be all the time, including here), each one will need to appear in its own table row.

Answer (score 0):

| table | test | 123 | 456 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| text | 7263 | 28383 |  |

It works.

Neat.